# Delete data from Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angular5

Hello I wanted to delete record from the realtime firebase database.I have got the key which I wanted to delete, but when I call remove function on reference is shows me error "Reference.remove failed: first argument must be a valid function."

[i had refer this docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

here is my code: 
home-customer.ts

```
 deleteLoad(load) {
    this.AuthProvider.removeNote(load.key).then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomeCustomerPage');
    });

  }
```

home-customer.html

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let load of LoadMaster">
<ion-item>
  Source:
  {{load.Source}}
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    Destination:
    {{load.Destination}}
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    Load Type:
    {{load.LoadType}}
</ion-item>
<button ion-button block (click)="UpdateLoad(load.key)">
  Update
</button>
<button ion-button block (click)="deleteLoad(load)">
  Delete
```

auth.ts

```
removeNote(key) {
  console.log('key'+key);
  return  firebase.database().ref(`/LoadMaster/`).remove(key);
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `firebase.database().ref(`/LoadMaster/`).child(key).remove()` or something simular

Comment: thanks @AndréKool it works!

Answer (score 0):

It's very sad since more then 3 year no answer...I think this answer will now help to others...

```
`var adaRef = firebase.database().ref('users/ada');
adaRef.remove()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
  });`
```

More can be found [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#remove)